# NetBeans deletes my resources when cleaning or renaming the project

Tags: file, netbeans, path, resources, delete-file

I have been having a troublesome issue working with NetBeans:
I have a program which uses big amounts of images, text files and sounds. I place them all on a "resources" folder inside the "build" folder. I have read that is the right way, since NetBeans uses this folder as "root" for the project. The BIG problem comes when I press by mistake "clean and build", or rename the project, since both actions ERASE THE WHOLE build directory. When this happens, I lose all of my data, and have to start over editing images, etc. Please notice that I make backups, but I still have to start over since last backup (the image files are changed very frequently), so this is not a definitive solution. Since this is a long-term Java project, it has happened several times, and it is very frustrating.

Is there a way to place my resources on a directory OUTSIDE of my project folder? In case there is not, can I somehow configure NetBeans so it places the deleted files somewhere (like trash bin or somewhere else)?

If it helps, I'm working under OSX system, but I think the same would apply for other operating systems.

I have seen similar questions have been posted, but not solved. Please help!!

Comment: Using the `build` folder is big NO as you have discovered. You should put them somewhere else and make Netbeans copy them over, but the way to do this depends on the kind of project. In some cases it might even happen automatically. Is a Java application? Web application? Are you using Maven? We need some more info.

Comment: Yes, it is a Java project. I have found difficult to access any folder out of the project folder. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked it out!

If you put the resources directory under the src folder of the proyect, when you clean and build the project, NetBeans will make a copy of this for you, on the build folder. This is not intuitive at all. I would still like to know if it is possible to access any folder out of the project folder, like the Desktop for example.

Comment: The first thing I usually do when creating a project is create a new package called `resources`. NetBeans will copy it to the build